# in_array() always returns true if numbers are in the array

Tags: php, laravel

This is code

```
<?php
$numbers = '3,5,1';
$exploded = array_filter(explode(',', $numbers));
$arr = [5, 6, 7, 8];

print_r($exploded);

foreach($arr as $num){
    echo "<br>---".$num.' --- is in array?  ';
    print_r(in_array($num, $arr));
}
?>
```

The output

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 5 [2] => 1 )
---5 --- is in array? 1
---6 --- is in array? 1
---7 --- is in array? 1
---8 --- is in array? 1
```

Why does it return always true even the number is not in the array?

Comment: You are checking against the wrong array - `in_array($num, $arr)` should be looking in `$exploded` I assume.

Comment: I think you're using the same array to check. and checking the same element is exist in array or not.

Comment: Hell yah, I made a mistake

Answer (score 0):

The correct code

```
<?php
$numbers = '3,5,1';
$exploded = array_filter(explode(',', $numbers));
$arr = [5, 6, 7, 8];

print_r($exploded);

foreach($arr as $num){
    echo "<br>---".$num.' --- is in array?  ';
    print_r(in_array($num, $exploded));
}
?>
```